# where to validate the json model?

Tags: java, json, gson

If you have a model for json objects, and you deserialize json from the server for example, where would you put the code to validate this json as in, if required fields are present, if their values are consistent with each other, etc?
The model object always has a noarg constructor, so should I have a method like validate that performs validation, called manually after deserializing the object to validate the whole model starting at the root?

Comment: Use model validation annotations

Comment: but this is not really an answer to my question, as you still have to call a validator somewhere, and I don't necessarily want to create such a validator manually in the code that uses the model, I would rather prefer to abstract it so that if something else uses the model then it can easily validate it.

Comment: But it's the model's responsibility to constraint the data to remain coherent. You should use model validation annotations. you can create your own if necessary...

Comment: the actual question here is *where* to call the validation logic. I can use things like bean validation in the model, but this is not a javaee app. This is actually just a library that does jws/etc, that is implements some specifications like json web signing, json web key, to be able to sign json objects before sending them over the wire. But I do not know how to do it properly. Maybe I should use validation annotation on the model, but do not expose the model itself to users of the library?

Comment: @MichałZegan your question actually requires an opinion-based answer and such questions are usually marked for closing at S.O.: some may prefer validate at the call-site invoking validation methods directly; some may prefer validate in "annotation" style; or strictly any of those due to techical restrictions. Just curious: why is your question tagged with `gson`? Is it fine for you to have custom validation annotations in your JSON mappings consumed by `Gson`?